# How to exclude trashed files when listing files in google drive

Tags: api, rest, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

I want to list all the files in google drive using [google drive api v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2) . But I want to exclude files in trash in the list

So I tried

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?trashed=false
```

as suggested in the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) But still I get files in the trash folder ,Am I missing something ? Or is it a known bug in drive api?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Problem was with query syntax,
proper query parameter  was

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse
```

Answer (score 0):

If some else also landed here trying to filter out Trashed file when using the Google Drive API, you can use `setQ(args...)` function like below,

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
          .setQ("mimeType='image/jpeg' and trashed=false")
          .setSpaces("drive")
          .setFields("items(id, title)")
          .execute();
```

More here - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files